# Can I install kdirstat on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: disk, disk-usage

Other disk analyzers are far inferior as they don't allow you to delete files from their interface. The to-ing and fro-ing back and forth between Nautilus and Disk Usage Analyzer  is slow, tedious and silly, especially as there is a Linux program that actually does the job properly.

I cannot find kdirstat in Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`kdirstat` is a transitional package, you should look for `k4dirstat` in Software Center

The package is available for Ubuntu 11.10 in PPA - see `ppa:jeromerobert/misc`

Comment: Only [available for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=k4dirstat).

Comment: Thanks Vadim! Your answer worked and k4dirstat is now running on my system!

Comment: @dunderhead if the answer made it work, you should mark it as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! On Debian 8.1, the package `k4dirstat` is available in the default repositories. I couldn't find `kdirstat`, and the download link on their website is broken, so thank goodness for this answer...

Answer (score 2):

kdirstat was migrated to the new k4dirstat package. I guess that's why you couldn't find it in the software-center.

Anyway, just run the following command in a terminal:
`sudo apt-get install k4dirstat` 
That would install the program in your system. Alternatively, click on [k4dirstat](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/k4dirstat) [image: Install k4dirstat] and it will let you install the program through software-center.

Comment: Only [available for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=k4dirstat).

Answer (score 2):

kdirstat is available in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdirstat

kdirstat is not available after 15.10 because it was superseded by k4dirstat (the KDE4 version).

`kdirstat` [is not available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdirstat) in the Ubuntu repos for 11.10 but 11.10 is no-longer supported so that's a non-issue.

You will be able to use it on the next version of Ubuntu apparently but no package was ever made for 11.10.

Do not install packages from 12.04 on your 11.10 system. Upgrade it to 12.04, then before 17.04 gets released upgrade to 14.04

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I was a bit confused but went ahead with the backport and k4dirstat is now running on my system!

Answer (score 1):

As per [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)'s website, kdirstat is dead. And '[qdirstat](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qdirstat/1.4-2)' is alive, and is the alternative.