# Advanced disk usage analyzing software?

Tags: software-recommendation, disk-usage

I can't really find a great disk analyzing software for Ubuntu.

The default apps in Ubuntu, Baobab (and df -h) do work, but there are no advanced features.

What I am looking for is like *glary utilities disk analysis*, to search for those file that take too much disk space.

[image: glary utilities disk analysis]

Comment: Can you explain what the advanced features are? Not everybody knows the `glary utilities disk analysis`. And how do you decide, that a file takes too much space? A video is such as big as it is - how can a software decide: it is too big?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two easy options, both available in the Software Center:

[GDMAP](http://gdmap.sourceforge.net/)

[image: gdmap screenshot]

[Filelight](http://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/)

[image: filelight screenshot]

If neither of these meet your needs,edit your question with the specific features you want. That helps us understand your question better.

Answer (score 5):

I've just installed k4dirstat. (It's almost identical to WinDirStat, if you're familiar with that Windows program. I believe Windirstat is based on kdirstat.)

The feature that I find most useful - and which is missing from a lot of disk usage software - is that you can delete files from within the program, saving the hassle of switching back and forth between nautilus or a terminal and the disk usage program to clean up files.

If you're using Ubuntu 11.10 you can't install k4dirstat from the Software Centre, but you can install a backport - see this thread: [Can I install kdirstat...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98094/can-i-install-kdirstat-on-ubuntu-11-10)