# Clean unneeded folders under /usr/share/doc/

Tags: cleanup

I would like to clean unneeded folders under /usr/share/doc/.

I found info on that folder here

https://coding-bootcamps.com/linux/filesystem/usr.html

I deleted the tor folder since I no longer have the program.

I have 4 empty folders.

Is is also safe to delete empty folders?

Comment: Do NOT delete files/folders placed by apt or other package managers. If you manually created it, then it's safe to delete. In the future, consider placing your manually-created stuff should be in /usr/local/ with a link to /usr/share/.

Comment: Why is it necessary to keep folders when the program is no longer installed? @user535733

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced disk usage analyzing software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98382/advanced-disk-usage-analyzing-software)

Comment: Depends upon how you uninstalled the software, and whether it was done properly. If the package manager fails to delete an empty directory, that might be a bug -- report it.

Comment: When I uninstall software, I follow the proper procedure. 90% of the time, I use synaptic package manager or use the command line to install programs and un-install programs. @user535733

Comment: My /usr/share/doc/ has 98 Mb. Since I have a 2 Tb system, it's now worth trying to trim it.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to delete empty folders, although empty folders take up very little disk space, so you won't save much disk space by deleting them. Many programs are able to create a new folder if it's necessary to replace an old folder that was deleted. Be careful that what you delete doesn't have any files in it, so that you don't do something irrevocable.